# Pgadmin4 specified user does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I installed `pgadmin4` on `ubuntu 18.04` with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
```

During installation as usual I was prompted for an email and password, so I provided my email and a  password. After installation when I try to login to `pgadmin4 homepage` with that email, I get the error:

```
specified user does not exist
```

I probably provided my email with some typo during installation. How do I solve this problem now? Is it possible to reset email without re-installing pgadmin4?

Answer (score 1):

I found the db location where my credentials are stored.

```
var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db
```

In `user` table credentials are stored.

Funny thing is that `postgres@localhost` is appended right before my email. While providing email didn't expected them to be appended to my email address.

So to update my credentials I installed [`SQLite 3`](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) and [`sqlitebrowser`](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) by following this [tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/install_sqlite_browser_ubuntu_1804/).

I had to change permission of `pgadmin` folder and `pgadmin4.db` file. Rest was easy-

- open sql browser
- click on open database
- click on browse data
- select table `user`
- update emeil address and save changes. Done